# Кастомный ListAdapter

Tags: android-sdk, android, listview

Здравствуйте!
Есть лист вью и стандартный адаптер. Как написать свой адаптер который будет в один элемен лист вью, состоящий из двух TextView , выводить данные. т.е. как на картинке

```
        id             Фамилия
```

[image]

Comment: @katso я выразился неверно. У меня именно фрагмент 

        public class MyEmployeFragment extends ListFragment {

Comment: @Deadkenny в итоге пишет null pointer exception в этой стоке

                listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.lv_employee_list);

Не совсем понял что это значит. У меня же в xml файле есть лист вью. Данные я посылаю в него по средствам  адаптера. Адаптер не пустой, переменные имею значения.

Comment: @Garf1eld если корневой элемент R.id.lv_employee_list это ListView, то не надо ничего искать. Просто надо привести текущий вид к ListView 
         listView = (ListView) getView()

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать [SimpleAdapter](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html), [пример](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/107-urok-48-ispolzuem-simpleadapter)

Comment: Сделал [как тут][1].
Выходит ошибка: 

        FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at ....MyEmployeFragment.onActivityCreated(MyEmployeFragment.java:63)


в строке 63 код: 

    listView.setAdapter(sAdapter);

  [1]: http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/107-urok-48-ispolzuem-simpleadapter

Comment: либо listView либо адаптер null

Comment: @Garf1eld listView проверьте на null

Comment: Данная активити является фрагментом.
        
listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lv_employee_list);

Comment: @Garf1eld активити не может быть фрагментом, в фрагменте:

@Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.вашЛэйаут, container, false);
  listView = (ListView) view .findViewById(R.id.lv_employee_list);

  return v;
 }

Comment: @Garf1eld Активити правда не может быть фрагментом. надо писать там

    listView = (ListView) getView();

Comment: Вот весь фрагмент:

public class MyEmployeFragment extends ListFragment {
   
//Переменные (не привожу)

        final String ATTRIBUTE_ID   = "p_id";
        final String ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "p_name";
        ListView listView;
    
        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        task    = new MyTask();
        task.execute();
    
        listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById (R.id.lv_employee_list);
    
       }

Comment: class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

                     @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
                        }
                        @Override
                        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                                            
        HttpActivity _http = new HttpActivity("бла");
            //бла бла бла
        _http.send();
        employer_name = _http.getA("p_name");
        employer_id = _http.getB("p_id");

Comment: // массивы данных

                String[] userId = {employer_id};
    
                String[] userName = {employer_name};
                ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>(
                        userId.length);
                Map<String, Object> m;
                for (int i = 0; i < userId.length; i++) {
                    m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    m.put(ATTRIBUTE_ID, userId[i]);
                    m.put(ATTRIBUTE_NAME, userName[i]);
                    data.add(m);
                }

Comment: // массив имен атрибутов, из которых будут читаться данные
                String[] from = { ATTRIBUTE_ID, ATTRIBUTE_NAME };
                // массив ID View-компонентов, в которые будут вставлять данные
                int[] to = { R.id.tw_employe_id, R.id.tw_employe_name };
    
                // создаем адаптер
                SimpleAdapter sAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), data, R.layout.list_item_employee,
                        from, to);

    
                listView.setAdapter(sAdapter);
    
    
    
                return null;

Comment: Я подозреваю, что Вы пытаетесь вызвать метод findViewById у активити, то есть искать вью в лэйауте, который вы пишете у активити тут: setContentView(R.layout.%layout_name), и соответственно не находите! listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.lv_employee_list); пробуйте так! Запустите пример не используя фрагмент

Comment: @Garf1eld Во-первых ваш AsyncTask может закончится раньше чем вы нашли listView. Во-вторых адаптер надо создать и добавить в listview в главном потоке.

Answer (score 0):

Чисто навскидку без проверки работы (выдрал "мысли" из старого проекта)
Делается разметка типа этой в файле например mylayout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView 
android:id="@+id/text1" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 <TextView  
android:id="@+id/text2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Может придется повыравнивать относительно друг друга поля в разметке.

Далее классик

```
public class ViewHolder2{
 TextView text1;
 TextView text2;
}
```

Далее

```
public class LogAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList<LogItem> data;
private LayoutInflater lInflater;

public LogAdapter(Context paramContext, ArrayList<LogItem> arrayList)
{
  lInflater = LayoutInflater.from(paramContext);
  data = arrayList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return data.size(); 
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return Integer.valueOf(arg0);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    ViewHolder2 localViewHolder = new ViewHolder2();

    if (convertView == null)
    {            
         convertView = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, null);
         localViewHolder.text1 = ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1));
         localViewHolder.text2 = ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2));
         convertView.setTag(localViewHolder); 
    }

    localViewHolder = (ViewHolder2)convertView.getTag();
    LogItem item = (LogItem)data.get(position);

    localViewHolder.text1.setText(item.text1);
            localViewHolder.text2.setText(item.text2);
            return convertView;
}
}
```

Далее

```
public class LogItem {  
public String text1;
public String text2;
}

public class MyActivity extends ListActivity{
private ArrayList<LogItem> Data;
private LogAdapter _LogAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

     loadLog(); //это метод в котором вы заполняете массив Data
 }

 protected void loadLog() {
 //это метод в котором вы заполняете неким образом массив Data  
     //и далее
      _LogAdapter = new LogAdapter(this, Data);
  setListAdapter(_LogAdapter);
 }
}
```

файл разметки my_activity.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ListView  
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

как-то так примерно. если где опечатался, не ругайтесь :) на лету сочинял